# On change event of dropdown ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a website, and at the registration page users are required to fill in their gender and age before continuing. My code is as such:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <!--some other stuff-->

          <%= f.label :gender %>
          <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(['M', 'F', 'N/A']), :id => "gender", :include_blank => "Please select..." %>

          <%= f.label :age %>
          <%= f.select :age, (17..75), :id => "age", :include_blank => "Please select..." %>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class='center'>
            <%= f.submit "Save and continue", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", :disabled => true %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" //other stuff></div>
          <label for="user_gender">Gender</label>
          <select id="user_gender" name="user[gender]"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="M">M</option>
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="N/A">N/A</option></select>

          <label for="user_age">Age</label>
          <select id="user_age" name="user[age]"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
// skipped this
<option value="75">75</option></select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="center">
            <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" disabled="disabled" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save and continue">
          </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $select_age = $("select#user_gender");
        $select_gender = $("select#user_age");

        var check_value = function () {
            alert("asdf");
            if ($select_gender.val() !== "" && $select_age.val() !== "") {
                $("input[name='commit']").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        };

        $select_age.change(check_value()) // I've also tried onchange 
        $select_gender.change(check_value())
    });
```

Whenever I select a new option from the dropdown, I should get an alert that says "asdf". But this doesn't happen. Why?

Answer (score 3):

try below code

```
$select_age.on("change", check_value()) // I've also tried onchange 
$select_gender.on("change", check_value())
```

Comment: check in your html,is id gender or age is present?

Comment: I did just check the html again. Turns out an id was slightly different (`user_age` and `user_gender`), but even after fixing that it still doesn't work.

Comment: changed id gender to user_gender

Comment: try $(document).on('change','#user_gender',function(){
    alert('asd');
});

Comment: Doesn't do anything either. I'll past the generated HTML in the question as well.

Comment: try $(document).on('change','#user_gender option',function(){ alert('asd'); });

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```js
let select_age, select_gender;

$(document).on('change','#gender', function(){
  select_age = $(this).val();
  $(document).on('change', '#age', function(){
    select_gender = $(this).val();
    if (select_age !== '' && select_gender !== '') {
      $("input[name='commit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option></option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <select id="age" name="age">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Send" name="commit" disabled>
```

This is because in your current code you're verifying for the value of those select tags when the page is loaded, and not whenever they make a change in the DOM, this way you can nest the verification of the `#age` select and finally check if the values of both `select` tags aren't the default that's blank.